# Make a series of boxes as big as possible constrained by parent

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to make a series of fixed aspect ratio (16/9) boxes as big as possible inside a fixed size parent element? The amount of child boxes varies as they are generated dynamically.

I was thinking of using flex-box, but don't know how to force a break depending on the dimensions of the parent or the amount of child elements.

A pure CSS solution would be nice, but using JavaScript is also an option.

Example with 5 boxes:

```
----------------
|    |    |    |
----------------
|    |    |
-----------
```

or 11 boxes in a horizontal parent element (width > height):

```
-------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
```

or 11 boxes in an almost square parent element:

```
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details please?
I didn't really understand your example. What is the parent div?

Comment: I added some more examples

Comment: @sqwk There are plenty of libraries to achieve this.. I recommend to you go through bootstrap lib  https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I think that **flexbox** will be the best solution in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? All you need is `flex-flow: row wrap;` in your container like so.

```css
.container {
  background: #f68a37;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 240px;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #8af637;
}
.container[large] {
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div large class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div large class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I have right now. I was hoping that there might be an easy way to prevent the boxes running outside a fixed size parent container (if there is too many of them) but I think the only thing I can do is tweak the min and max-width values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for.

HTML

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;//making it full screen, or you can also use fixed size here
  background #fff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 20%; // 100/the number of children you want, in the case 5
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #fff; // just for showing the boxes
}
.wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: deepskyblue; //just for demonstrating
  color: white;
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e34a5gbx/1/